"Error converting data type varchar to bigint" when creating pivot table
I'm (very) new to SQL and working on a mini-project as practice. I want to create a pivot table summarizing all the findings nicely but having some trouble and get an error:

Error converting data type varchar to bigint

I have a duration in seconds but want to format it as XX hours, XX minutes, XX seconds in the table. The chunk of code giving me the headache is:
SELECT 'Total hours ridden', [Member], [Casual]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         member_casual, 
         --ride_id,
         --DATENAME(MONTH, started_at) AS [Month],
         --rideable_type,
         --day_of_week,
         ride_length_in_sec = CONCAT(
            SUM(CAST(ride_length_in_sec AS BIGINT))/3600, ' ', 'hours', ' ',
            (SUM(CAST(ride_length_in_sec AS BIGINT))%3600)/60, ' ', 'minutes', ' ',
            (SUM(CAST(ride_length_in_sec AS BIGINT))%3600)%60, ' ', 'seconds')
     FROM
         AllCombined
     GROUP BY 
         member_casual) AS Src2
PIVOT
    (MAX(ride_length_in_sec)    
        FOR member_casual 
            IN ([Member], [Casual])
    ) AS Pvt2

I'm pretty sure it's the CONCAT bit that's causing the trouble because I've successfully used that chunk of code in a different query in the SELECT clause.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
So far, I have tried changing the datatype of the column to BIGINT in hopes that getting rid of CAST might work, but just throws the same error. I tried using the other convention (using the + signs) to concatenate, but nothing.

There is no SQL Server 2020 - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 - so which one is it then?

I've removed the references from your post to SQL Server 2020 because, like @marc_s says, it doesn't exist. It only causes confusion.

I can't replicate your problem: db<>fiddle Please [edit] your question to provide us with a full [mre], including DDL and DML for your table and data. (I suspect the problem is not your question, but your design, and ride_length_in_sec is in fact a string based data type, and you have bad data; the solution to that is fix your design.)

Sorry my mistake—I'm using 2022.

The data is straight from the source so I don't know how that could be the problem.

Why, out of interest, do you CAST ride_length_in_sec to a bigint? Are you expecting the total ride time of all people to be more than 2,147,483,647 seconds (596,523 hours/24,855 days/~68 years)? That's a lot of ride time; it would take 100 people riding 8 hours a day, every day ,over 2 years to get that much ride time. Surely the base type of your column (int) is more than enough.

I just added a screenshot of the table. And there are roughly 5 million rows, each with a ride time, so they must be converted to bigint. The column is computed from started_at and ended_at. I have made the column as an INT as well as BIGINT just to try running the CONCAT without having to CAST it but it didn't work :(

Why are the seconds being stored in char columns?

@shawnt00 I'm confused. Their datatype is INT.  How are the seconds being stored in char columns?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. If you want to supply sample data, do so as DDL and DML statements (as I mentioned earlier).

What does SELECT ride_length_in_sec FROM dbo.AllCombined WHERE ride_length_in_sec IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(bigint,ride_length_in_sec) IS NULL; return?

I'm sorry. I'm very new to this. I'll delete that! @ThomA

It returns:
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'. @ThomA

Shoot, sorry ... TRY_CONVERT(bigint,ride_length_in_sec) IS NULL.

That returns ride_length_in_sec

We really need a [mre] then; if you can't replicate the problem, we can't help you other than guess, and [so] isn't a site for making guesses.

Let me work on that. Thank you for the help so faR!

Modifying ThomA's example to produce the error message, db<>fiddle, it would seem that your ride_length_in_sec column is some kind of a char-based data type and contains values that have non-digit characters in them.

Try something like this:
SELECT 
'Total hours ridden' AS [Total Hours Ridden], 
[Member], 
[Casual] FROM
(SELECT 
     member_casual, 
     total_seconds = SUM(CAST(ride_length_in_sec AS BIGINT))
 FROM
     AllCombined
 GROUP BY 
     member_casual) AS Src2 PIVOT
(MAX(total_seconds)    
    FOR member_casual 
        IN ([Member], [Casual])
) AS Pvt2 CROSS APPLY
(SELECT 
     [Member] = CONCAT([Member]/3600, ' hours ', ([Member]%3600)/60, ' minutes ', ([Member]%3600)%60, ' seconds'),
     [Casual] = CONCAT([Casual]/3600, ' hours ', ([Casual]%3600)/60, ' minutes ', ([Casual]%3600)%60, ' seconds')
) AS Formatted;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
